# Which Swift datatype do I use for currency

Tags: ios, swift

I have an iOS application that will be performing a lot of basic arithmetic on numbers representing USD currency (eg 25.00 representing $25.00).

I have gotten into a lot of trouble using the datatype Double in other languages like Java and Javascript so I would like to know the best datatype to use for currency in Swift.

Comment: Just curious, what kind of problems did you run into while using double as a datatype for currency ?

Comment: @AbhishekMukherjee I ran into problems comparing values. When I thought 5.20 == 5.20 it was actually 5.200000001 == 5.20

Comment: That's been discussed quite a lot. The correct type to use in Java is BigDecimal.

Comment: For my project, I was originally storing currency amounts as `Int` (multiplying the dollar amount by 100 to store, and then reversing it and casting as a `Double` when accessing it.) However, after implementing a multi-currency system where currencies have different numbers of decimal places, keeping track of whether it was the stored `Int` or accessed `Double` amount and whether it was in the original currency or base currency, the `Int` approach had too much overhead. Math was easier when using `Double`, but in the end I also recommend `NSDecimalNumber`.

Comment: @userx The problem I found using Doubles is that just subtracting leads to REALLY long floating values, I don't know why. For example, something as easy as 650.50 - 300.50 would result in 350.0038420489380933, and I don't know why.

Comment: @JozemiteApps read http://www.toves.org/books/float/ and you'll learn why. Floating point values are inherently imprecise for many values within their range.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I suggest you start with a `typealias` for [`Decimal`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal).  Example:

```
typealias Dollars = Decimal
let a = Dollars(123456)
let b = Dollars(1000)
let c = a / b
print(c)
```

Output:

```
123.456
```

If you are trying to parse a monetary value from a string, use a `NumberFormatter` and set its `generatesDecimalNumbers` property to `true`.

Comment: Does this approach maintain the number of digits after the decimal? Or will it create an approximation of the decimal that could stretch many digits passed the decimal point?

Comment: I like this approach the most because it is feels the easiest to use.

Comment: Why not just make a Money class?

Comment: @Rob Why make a class when you can just use `typealias`.

Comment: This is a *terrible* solution for _currency_, because initialising a `Decimal` with a `Double` can easily lead to rounding errors. For example: `Decimal(2.13) == 2.129999999999999488`

Comment: My answer doesn't suggest converting from a `Double` to a `Decimal`. My answer shows how to accurately create a `Decimal` with fractional digits by dividing by a power of 10.

Comment: nope, this will lose precision because there's no way to represent 0.2 in binary

Comment: I'm not sure what you're responding to, @OMGPOP, but in case it's me: `Decimal` represents a number as an integer (the ‘significand’ or ‘mantissa’) times a (possibly negative) power of ten (the ‘exponent’). A `Decimal` can represent `0.2` exactly (by storing 2 as the significand and -1 as the exponent), and `Decimal(2) / Decimal(10)` produces such a representation. You can check it for yourself by printing `(Decimal(2) / Decimal(10))._mantissa` and `(Decimal(2) / Decimal(10))._exponent`.

Answer (score 45):

Use [`Decimal`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal), and *make sure you initialize it properly*!

### CORRECT

```swift
// Initialising a Decimal from a Double:
let monetaryAmountAsDouble = 32.111
let decimal: Decimal = NSNumber(floatLiteral: 32.111).decimalValue
print(decimal) // 32.111  
let result = decimal / 2
print(result) // 16.0555 


// Initialising a Decimal from a String:
let monetaryAmountAsString = "32,111.01"

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal

if let number = formatter.number(from: monetaryAmountAsString) {
    let decimal = number.decimalValue
    print(decimal) // 32111.01 
    let result = decimal / 2.1
    print(result) // 15290.9571428571428571428571428571428571 
}
```

### INCORRECT

```swift
let monetaryAmountAsDouble = 32.111
let decimal = Decimal(monetaryAmountAsDouble) 
print(decimal) // 32.11099999999999488  

let monetaryAmountAsString = "32,111.01"
if let decimal = Decimal(string: monetaryAmountAsString, locale: Locale(identifier: "en_US")) {
    print(decimal) // 32  
}
```

**Performing arithmetic operations on `Double`s or `Float`s representing currency amounts will produce inaccurate results.** This is because the `Double` and `Float` types cannot accurately represent most decimal numbers. [More information here](https://floating-point-gui.de/).

Bottom line: 
**Perform arithmetic operations on currency amounts using `Decimal`s or `Int`**

Comment: Thanks for showing proper way to initialize it. Can you also show proper way to convert ```Decimal``` back to ```String```? I am not sure if other answers on StackOverflow are showing that correctly or not.

Comment: Would using Decimal(floatLiteral:) be equal to using NSNumber(floatLiteral:).decimalValue?

Comment: @Roberto for whatever reason, Decimal(floatLiteral:) produces an incorrect (32.11099999999999488) result.

Comment: Using `NSNumber(floatLiteral: 32.111).decimalValue` is not correct either. The problem si that there is a conversion from a decadic number (floating point literal) to a lossy binary number (`double`) and then to a a decimal number (`Decimal`). If you want precision, initialize always from a String.

Comment: `Decimal(string:locale:)` does not recognize grouping separators. With "32111.01" the result will be correct.

Answer (score 4):

There's a really nice lib called [Money](https://github.com/danthorpe/Money):

```
let money: Money = 100
let moreMoney = money + 50 //150
```

There a lot of nice features besides that, such as type-safe currencies:

```
let euros: EUR = 100
let dollars: USD = 1500
euros + dollars //Error
```

> Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'EUR' (aka '_Money') and 'USD' (aka '_Money')

Comment: Warning with this class: It does not conform to NSCoding, meaning you will not be able to save values of type Money using NSCoder. Xcode will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

The [Flight-School/Money](https://github.com/Flight-School/Money) is probably the best choice for a project full of monies.

In the [ending of README](https://github.com/Flight-School/Money#alternatives-to-consider) @mattt provides a nice solution for a simple Money type:

```
struct Money {
    enum Currency: String {
      case USD, EUR, GBP, CNY // supported currencies here
    }

    var amount: Decimal
    var currency: Currency
}
```

Chapter 3 in 'Flight School Guide to Swift Numbers' is provides excellent intro into the topic.

Answer (score 1):

We use this approach with `Currency` being a huge enum that has been generated in advance (don't forget a monetary value is just a number without its currency - they both belong together):

```
struct Money: Hashable, Equatable {

    let value: Decimal
    let currency: Currency
}

extension Money {

    var string: String {
        CurrencyFormatter.shared.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `Decimal` and its initializer:

```swift
Decimal(string: "12345.67890", locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US"))
```

When considering the other answers, please note that `Float` and `Double` literals affect the accuracy of the Decimal result. The same applies to the `NumberFormatter`.

```swift
Decimal(5.01) // 5.009999999999998976 ❌

Decimal(floatLiteral: 5.01) // 5.009999999999998976 ❌

NSNumber(floatLiteral: 0.9999999).decimalValue // 0.9999999000000001 ❌

let decimalFormatter = NumberFormatter()
decimalFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
decimalFormatter.number(from: "0.9999999")?.decimalValue // 0.9999999000000001 ❌

Decimal(string: "5.01", locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US")) // 5.01 ✅
Decimal(string: "0.9999999", locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US")) // 0.9999999 ✅
```