# Casting currency values from JSON to NSDecimalNumber

Tags: json, swift, double, currency, nsdecimalnumber

I get the following JSON response from an API.

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      "actual_price": 30,
      "offered_deal_price": 16,
      "pending_balance": 12.8
    }
  ]
}
```

All those values are prices. Which means they can be round values or floating values.

I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28421176/1077789) that you should use `NSDecimalNumber` type for currency values. I'm having trouble converting these JSON values.

Doing this,

```
json["pending_balance"] as! NSDecimalNumber
```

failed with the following error.

**Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x10423ccf0) to 'NSDecimalNumber' (0x1046cf1f0)**

Trying to cast it to `NSDecimal` resulted in this

**Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x7f9102f79f68) to 'C.NSDecimal' (0x10f23d6e0)**.

I *can* however, cast it to Swift types like `Float` or `Double` without an issue.

Anyone got an idea what's the problem with `NSDecimalNumber`? Or is it safe to go ahead with `Float` or `Double`? If so which one is the best for currency values?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is an indication that you are trying to cast to the wrong type.
The value is deserialized from JSON into a `NSNumber`, which is seamlessly bridged into a `Double` native swift type.

Rather than casting, you should try with a conversion:

```
NSDecimalNumber(decimal: (json["pending_balance"] as! NSNumber).decimalValue)
```

or

```
NSDecimalNumber(double: json["pending_balance"] as! Double)
```

but probably there are other ways to do the conversion.

Comment: Thanks, Antonio. I went with the first suggestion and it works.

Comment: Note: this will solve the casting issue but not the original problem of inprecise floating point representation. The right solution is to convert the string in Swift to NSDecimalNumber, not in JS.