# swift: issue in converting string to double

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Here is a simple code in Xcode 7.3.1 playground:

**`var str = "8.7"
print(Double(str))`**

the output is suprising:
**`Optional(8.6999999999999993)`**

also, `Float(str)` gives: `8.69999981`

Any thoughts or reasons on this guys?
Any references to this would be appreciated.

Also, how should I then convert "8.7" to 8.7 as Double (or Float)?

**Edit**

in swift:

**(str as NSString).doubleValue returns 8.7**

Now, that is Ok. But my question, still, does not get a complete answer. We have found an alternative but why can we not rely on Double("8.7"). Please, give a deeper insight on this.

**Edit 2**

("6.9" as NSString).doubleValue // prints 6.9000000000000004

So, the question opens up again.

Comment: use print(Double(str)!)

Comment: If your question is about 8.7 vs 8.69999981 then you should read [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: "Double-precision floating-point format is a computer number format that occupies 8 bytes (64 bits) in computer memory and represents a wide, dynamic range of values by using a floating point.", therefore you must specify the "precision" of the value ( precision is the number of digits in a number ).

Comment: @l'L'l, Martin 
but why would converting "8.7" into Double not lead to 8.7 but 8.69999999999991. What is the point in doing that?
And if that is really to do at hardware level then, Swift should have handled it. (like it converts it to 8.7 for .doubleValue but not for Double("8.7"))

Comment: The double value of `8.7` can be `8.699999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875000...`, you need to set the precision as said before `print(String(format:"%.1f", Double(str)!))`

Comment: @l'L'l, then why does (str as NSString).doubleValue return 8.7. it should also return something like 8.699999999991

Comment: It obviously converts it automatically to `%.1f`. You can test it by putting in `X.X` for the value and it should return `0.0` on error...

Comment: This question turned out to be more interesting than I thought initially ...

Comment: In Swift 5.1 this problem is again coming and even after doing all the answers given, the double still loses its precision :/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are two different issues here. First – as already mentioned in
the comments – a binary floating point number cannot represent the
number `8.7` precisely. Swift uses the IEEE 754 standard for representing
single- and double-precision floating point numbers, and if you assign

```
let x = 8.7
```

then the closest representable number is stored in `x`, and that is

```
8.699999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
```

Much more information about this can be found in the excellent
Q&A [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

---

The second issue is: Why is the number sometimes printed as "8.7"
and sometimes as "8.6999999999999993"?

```
let str = "8.7"
print(Double(str)) // Optional(8.6999999999999993)

let x = 8.7
print(x) // 8.7
```

Is `Double("8.7")` different from `8.7`? Is one more precise than 
the other?

To answer these questions, we need to know how the `print()` 
function works:

- If an argument conforms to `CustomStringConvertible`, the print function  calls its `description` property and prints the result
  to the standard output.
- Otherwise, if an argument conforms to `CustomDebugStringConvertible`,
  the print function calls is `debugDescription` property and prints
  the result to the standard output.
- Otherwise, some other mechanism is used. (Not imported here for our
  purpose.)

The `Double` type conforms to `CustomStringConvertible`, therefore

```
let x = 8.7
print(x) // 8.7
```

produces the same output as

```
let x = 8.7
print(x.description) // 8.7
```

But what happens in

```
let str = "8.7"
print(Double(str)) // Optional(8.6999999999999993)
```

`Double(str)` is an *optional*, and `struct Optional` does *not*
conform to `CustomStringConvertible`, but to
`CustomDebugStringConvertible`. Therefore the print function calls
the `debugDescription` property of `Optional`, which in turn
calls the `debugDescription` of the underlying `Double`.
Therefore – apart from being an optional – the number output is
the same as in

```
let x = 8.7
print(x.debugDescription) // 8.6999999999999993
```

But what is the difference between `description` and `debugDescription`
for floating point values? From the Swift source code one can see
that both ultimately call the `swift_floatingPointToString`
function in [Stubs.cpp](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/stubs/Stubs.cpp), with the `Debug` parameter set to `false` and `true`, respectively.
This controls the precision of the number to string conversion:

```
  int Precision = std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10;
  if (Debug) {
    Precision = std::numeric_limits<T>::max_digits10;
  }
```

For the meaning of those constants, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits:

- `digits10` – number of decimal digits that can be represented without change,
- `max_digits10` – number of decimal digits necessary to differentiate all values of this type.

So `description` creates a string with less decimal digits. That
string can be converted to a `Double` and back to a string giving
the same result.
`debugDescription` creates a string with more decimal digits, so that
any two different floating point values will produce a different output.

---

**Summary:**

- Most decimal numbers cannot be represented exactly as a binary
  floating point value.
- The `description` and `debugDescription` methods of the floating
  point types use a different precision for the conversion to a
  string. As a consequence,
- printing an *optional* floating point value uses a different precision for the conversion than printing a non-optional value.

Therefore in your case, you probably want to unwrap the optional
before printing it:

```
let str = "8.7"
if let d = Double(str) {
    print(d) // 8.7
}
```

For better control, use `NSNumberFormatter` or formatted
printing with the `%.<precision>f` format.

Another option can be to use `(NS)DecimalNumber` instead of `Double`
(e.g. for currency amounts), see e.g. [Round Issue in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37794622/round-issue-in-swift).

Comment: could you please, take a look at the last edit in the question.

Comment: @v-i-s-h-a-l: `("6.9" as NSString).doubleValue` prints `"6.9"` in my test. But even if it didn't: You cannot rely on a certain output, unless you use a number formatter.

Answer (score 3):

I would use:

```
let doubleValue = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(str)?.doubleValue
```