# Moya/Alamofire request variables issue

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, moya

I am writing an **iOS app** in **Swift** and using **[Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya)** as Network layer.

I am making a request object to be send in body and using Moya to perform API call:

```
struct OrderRequest{
var amount:Double
}

let order=OrderRequest(amount:100.57)
```

I am converting this object to JSONDict and then to Data.

```
if let json = JSONDict(from: order) {
  let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])
}
```

I am performing Moya request and internally it's using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire).

ISSUE:

Instead of sending the accurate value of **100.57**, it sends **100.56999999999999**

My question is about below line:

```
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8)
```

It converts data from DATA to STRING. This is converting **100.57** to **100.56999999999999**

How can it be solved? Am I making the DATA object incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

That's how binary floating point arithmetic works. About 15 digits precision for `Double`, and much less for `Float`. What's wrong is not the code, but your expectations. And this is the same in C, C++, Objective-C, Java and so on. Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150791/swift-impossible-to-round-a-double-correctly) you can find the same issue