# Convert JSON data to Double in Swift

Tags: json, swift, double

I receive the following JSON response:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "value": 519.6365
}
```

But when I convert the `value` to `Double`, I get: `519.63649999999996`

How to keep the original value? (without rounding it)

Comment: See [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Note that printing an *optional* double uses a different precision than printing a non-optional double (compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39770303/swift-issue-in-converting-string-to-double). So unwrapping the (presumably) optional makes it at least *appear* as you expect (even if it does not change the precision issue).

Answer (score 1):

In such case using Foundation's NSNumber would be better solution.
Converts the json value to *NSNumber* and it can always be *downcast* to *Double Value*

In Swift 4 -

```
let json = [
    "id": 1,
    "value": 519.6365
]

let value = (json["value"]! as NSNumber).doubleValue
print(value)  // Outputs - 519.6365
```

In cases where server sends the value as string, it would need to be first casted as String  then to double value as -

```
value = (json["value"]! as NSString).doubleValue
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use `NSNumber` with a `Codable` struct (Swift 5) to encode the struct as JSON automatically, it'll just display an error: `Type 'MyCodableStruct' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'`.

Answer (score -1):

Double is like long Float,

> Double represents a 64-bit floating-point number.
>
> Float represents a 32-bit floating-point number.

So when you cast to Double, 32 bits is added to the variable, causing the change you see.

To keep the number as it is, you need to cast the variable to Float meaning the smaller floating point number.

```
var value:Float = 519.6365
var valueDouble = Double(value) // 519.636474609375
Float(valueDouble) // 519.6365
```

Comment: Both `value` and `valueDouble` hold the value `519.636474609375`, they are only *printed* with a different precision. And nowhere in the above problem is a Float cast to Double.