# How to keep original double value while parsing in json swift?

Tags: json, swift, double, swifty-json

I received the following response from server

```
"transactionInfo": {
      "currencyCode": "MYR",
      "total": 472.23,
      "roomCurrencyCode": "MYR",
      "roomTotal": 472.23
}
```

but when I am trying to convert using SwiftyJson and map using below code

```
struct TransactionInfoModel: Codable {
   var currencyCode: String
   var total: Double
   var roomCurrencyCode: String
   var roomTotal: Double
}
```

then I get values like below:

```
"currencyCode": "MYR",
"total": 472.23000000000002,
"roomCurrencyCode": "MYR",
"roomTotal": 472.23000000000002
```

Please suggest how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Double can’t represent certain values exactly. Use Decimal, slower but safer for financial data

Comment: @CodeDifferent Thanx but I changed Double to Decimal but still facing the same issue.

Comment: I have debugged the code and find out that double value gets change while converting to JSON using SwiftyJson.

Comment: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/930

Answer (score -1):

Swift uses the IEEE 754 standard for representing single- and double-precision.

> [swift: issue in converting string to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39770303/swift-issue-in-converting-string-to-double)
>   Marting has answered clearly your question.