# In Swift 4, what is the correct way of typecasting a String value to a Float value?

Tags: swift, xcode, floating-point

I came across a situation where the following code does not work as expected in a project whereas works fine in Playground.

```
strtof("0.9", nil) //expected to return 0.9
Float("0.9")! //expected to return 0.9
```

Here are the screen shots when I execute the same code in project vs Playground.

***XCode's Console:***

[image]

***Playground:***

[image]

Is this difference intended?

Comment: Related: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), and possibly [swift: issue in converting string to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39770303/swift-issue-in-converting-string-to-double)

Comment: @MartinR, thanks, but I also wanted to know how it's being done in Playground?

Comment: @RikeshSubedi Almost every usage of this String initializer that I've seen has been inappropriate. 99% of the time people are better suited using a number formatter, to more precisely control the number of digits, rounding style, etc.

Comment: @Alexander, correct, but I needed the value so that I can pass a test case. Basically I am testing a method which returns UIColor from rgba string eg. rgba(255,0,0,0.9)

Comment: Please post code, console output, etc as text (not images) so it is searchable

Comment: @Ashley, there's code as well, at the top. The result of two different executions are posted as images.

Comment: @RikeshSubedi What part of testin UIColor involves converting a float to a string? o.0

Comment: @RikeshSubedi Please post them as text rather than images (or in addition)

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because decimal 0.9 can't be represented as a 32 bit floating point value (`Float` in Swift). The closest value just happens to be 0.899999976.

Both the debugger (Xcode's console) and playground do compute the exact same value.

It's just the way the output is generated which differs. Playgrounds seem to round the result while the debugger shows all significant digits.

Comment: True, making it Double prints it as 0.90000000000000002, does not give the correct answer there also.