# Issue in converting string to double

Tags: swift, string, type-conversion, double

I have mobile bank app. 
When user type amount, then convert string to double i have problem 
user typed amount example "8.7" is 8.699999999999999 and when i send request it sending 8.699999999999999 
what can i do, to fix it?

I have tried this post:

[swift: issue in converting string to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39770303/swift-issue-in-converting-string-to-double)

var amount = "8.7" 
var amountDouble = Double(amount)!

var amount = "8.7" .     //"8.7"
var amountDouble = Double(amount)! //8.699999999999999

Answer (score 1):

This imprecision is exactly why `Double` isn't an appropriate datatype for financial domains. Use `Decimal` instead, which is have perfect precision within its legal range.