# Swift 2.2 : Decimal conversion not working as expected in Xcode

Tags: swift, swift2

Trying to convert string to decimal and shows unexpected values for some strings such as 8.80 and 9.80 , tried to run some code in playground and Xcode, please refer below screen shots. I suspect this as a apple bug, Any suggestions why does the Double append zeros to some values ?

Also i have noticed using print you get expected value, but the variable is actually holding the big value with appended zeros, please refer screen shot, I still consider this as a bug.

```
var totalStr = "8.80"
var total = Double(totalStr)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate

Comment: Are you doing something money related? If so: do NOT use floating point numbers.

Comment: @luk2302 yes what would be right type to use ?

Comment: Integers! Or some loss-less data structure. Floating point is lossy.

Comment: (NS)DecimalNumber is another option.

Comment: @MartinR i dont see a proper answer what needs to be done when you run into such situations, I did refer to the post you marked duplicate of and most of the answers are not correct or too complicated and not even marked as answer . Would you like to check proper answer for this.

Comment: You asked why `Double(totalStr)` prints as `"8.8000000000000001"` and that *is* answered in the linked to Q&A. @luk2302 also provided a link which explains the general problem. Another one is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken. `Double` is a *binary* floating point number and that cannot represent the value `8.8` exactly. It is definitely not a Apple bug.

Comment: Here is another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37794622/round-issue-in-swift.

Comment: @MartinR I am a bit confused had a look at your link, they are suggesting to us NSDecimalNumber, But when i use NSDecimal number i don't see any convincing results.I have attached the screen shot to the question now.

Comment: That is a flaw in the Playground (which apparently uses `.doubleValue` for display). Try `let totalString = "9.8"; print(NSDecimalNumber(string: totalString))` in a compiled project, or `NSDecimalNumber(string: totalString).decimalValue` in the Playground.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, I see that when I print in xCode project I get right value but the variable still holds the big value and does not solve the problem by using .doubleValue or NSDecimalNumber , Any Suggestions, I think its time to mark this as a question and not duplicate. Please refer my screen shot.